# How to read JNDI Key value using Java Config from weblogic server

Tags: java, weblogic, jndi

We are moving from xml configuration to use java configuration. 
I was able to read JNDI datasource using Java config, but not able to find a way to read JNDI Key values using Java config.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Thankyou,
Kranthi.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want to do? Here is an example of how to list JNDI values: http://javaoraclesoa.blogspot.com/2012/09/monitoring-datasources-on-weblogic.html See the `listContext` function

Comment: Thankyou for your response, what i am trying to achieve is , i have JNDI admin in weblogic server where we set JNDI Key values. We used to read these values into our java applications using jee:jndilookup like <jee:jndi-lookup id="genericId" jndi-name="jndikeyname" />, then we autowire genericId where needed. With Java configuration, i need to know how to convert jee:jndi-lookup into java code, is there any annotation? or is there any other way?. Hope this is clear.

Comment: I am able to resolve this by adding a bean in one of my java config file like :
@Bean
    public String beanName() throws NamingException {
        Context context = new InitialContext();
        return (String)context.lookup("jndi key");
    }